# Is there a standard notation for basis states in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, quantum-states

Given a complete set of orthogonal basis states $|e_i\rangle$ one can form any vector $|a\rangle = \sum_i a_i |e_i\rangle$.

Is there a standard notation to separate out a basis state from a general state? For example having the basis states in bold? e.g. $|a\rangle$ and $|\mathbf{e}_3\rangle$. Or a particular font? $|\mathfrak{e}_3\rangle$

For example there are special vectors called normal vectors which we denote with a hat $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$. I wondered if there was any equivalent notation to distinguish basis states?

(Of course any state can be a basis state, but in the context of an equation you might want to distinguish some states as basis states.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a good notation for basis states? The one you showed in the question is pretty good.

Is there a *widely recognized standard* notation for basis states, in the sense that you could flip through the pages of a textbook, glance at the equations, and immediately recognize with high confidence which states are being used as basis states? No, there is no such standard. Fonts, subscripts/superscripts, and other decorations vary from author to author and even from chapter to chapter. This is a case where you just have to find where the author defines the conventions that she/he happens to be using in that particular context.

Comment: Favorite example for possible degree of non-standard notation: The quantum information notation for the Schmidt decomposition, where it is not uncommon to write $|\psi\rangle=\sum_i \lambda_i |i\rangle_A |i\rangle_B$, where $|i\rangle_A$ and  $|i\rangle_B$ are *different* orthonormal bases, which moreover are not fixed, but computed from $|\psi\rangle$.  (Rule of thumb (for the OP): If there is a way to abuse notation, some physicists will do it.)

Comment: @Norbert Yes, I had that idea but then I thought why not just use $|A_i\rangle$ and $|B_i\rangle$, but yes $|i\rangle_A$ and $|i\rangle_B$ does make it clear they are basis states in different bases. I quite like this notation. Maybe I was using the notation wrong. I guess you could write $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i A_i |i\rangle_A= \sum_i B_i |i\rangle_B$. Or $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i \psi^A_i |i\rangle_A$